# Does the sum of two convex functions with global minimizers have a global minimizer?

Tags: calculus, functions, optimization, convex-analysis

If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are two convex functions defined in $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$. Suppose $f(x)$ has a global minimizer $x_1 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ but not necessarily the unique global minimizer.
Similarly, $g(x)$ has a global minimizer $x_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ but not necessarily the unique global minimizer.
Does there exist a global minimizer in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for the function $f(x) + g(x)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would expect that the claim is true for $n=1$, or if $f$ and $g$ are quadratic functions, or if one of $f,g$ is strongly convex.

Here is a counterexample for the general case:
$$
f(x) := \max(y,0), \quad
g(x) := \max(e^x - y,0).
$$
Both functions are convex.
In addition, $f\ge0$, $g\ge0$, $f(0,0)=0$, $g(0,1)=0$. And $f$ and $g$ have global minimizers.
The infimum of $f+g$ is zero:
$$
f(-n,0) + g(-n,0)= e^{-n} \to 0.
$$
However, zero is not attained: $f(x,y) + g(x,y)=0$ implies $y\le0$ and $e^x\le y$, which is impossible.

If one raises $f$ and $g$ to power $p\in \mathbb N$ then  one gets $p$-times continuously differentiable functions with the same property.